# Allow HTML style attribute for filtred HTML

Tags: wysiwyg

I'm using the Wysiwyg module with CKEditor 3.6.6.2.7696. The HTML attributes is disallowed in HTML text format, so I can't use `font-size` and `text-align`.
Any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

go to `admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html`

[image]

In the limit allowed HTML tags, add the tags that you need. You could view source to see what tags are being added when you're trying to font-size and text align and then add them here.

go to:

`/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Advanced` (for Filter HTML)

Then under Advanced Content Filter, select disabled.

[image]

Comment: I mean inline css <p style='text-align:center'>, I think that's prevented by CKEditor

Comment: @learner123 Did you add `<p>` as allowed tag?

Comment: Yes, I did, but CKEditor removes tags attributes

Comment: @learner123 try unchecking `Correct faulty and chopped off HTML`

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunatly

Comment: try disabling the content filter (see updated answer)

Comment: Sorry for my late comment, I don't have this option in my Wysiwig version, so I disabled "Verify Html" option, see the screenshot https://snag.gy/E1AXNd.jpg